# 404 File not found when using JSDelivr and Github to host GLTF model in AFrame

Tags: cdn, aframe, gltf, jsdelivr

I'm new to A-Frame, and I'm trying to use a CDN to host a GLTF model with JsDelivr. Could someone walk me through step-by-step to use GitHub and JsDelivr? No matter what I try, the model won't show up, and I'm getting a 404 file not found error in the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn’t look like an A-Frame specific issue but a hosting problem. Can you download the model by just visiting the URL? Without code to run and debug it will be hard to help any further. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks so much for your reply. I actually get the same problem on Glitch, so yes I think its a problem with how I'm uploading the files or how I'm using the cdn itself.

Comment: If it's a hosting problem, what are some solutions?

Comment: I used glitch, and got rid of the 404 error- thank you! But the model still will not show - I get this error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.js:28
    at three.js:29102

Comment: Without code and seeing the model it’ll be hard to help. Edit your question with a glitch link https://glitch.com/~aframe